# Is the property "accessExternalSchema" still relevant in current versions of xjc and jaxws-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, jax-ws, xjc

While updating our Spring Boot projects to Spring Boot 3 we also updated the JAX-WS Maven Plugin dependency to the one hosted by the [Eclipse Foundation](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/metro-jax-ws/jaxws-maven-plugin/). We use the following plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <xjcArgs>
            <xjcArg>-mark-generated</xjcArg>
        </xjcArgs>
         <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
         <extension>true</extension>
         <!-- Needed with JAXP 1.5 -->
         <vmArgs>
             <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
         </vmArgs>
     </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

- Is the xjc parameter `-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all` still relevant?
- Will it be moved/renamed to `-Djakarta.xml.accessExternalSchema=all` at some point?

It seems that it was introduced in Java 8 to allow better control to external XSD. However, the [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/properties/properties.html) by Oracle is outdated ("The Java Tutorials have been written for JDK 8. Examples and practices described in this page don't take advantage of improvements introduced in later releases and might use technology no longer available.") and I have troubles to find anything newer.